# Parallel multicore plyr with early exit on error

Tags: r, parallel-processing, plyr, parallel-foreach

When specifying `.parallel=TRUE` in a call to one of the `plyr` functions, it will stubbornly evaluate all instances even if the first evaluation already throws an error:

```
doMC::registerDoMC()
plyr::llply(rep(FALSE, 100000), stopifnot, .parallel=TRUE)
```

The above example runs almost a minute on my machine, spawning *a few* processes on the way. If `.parallel=TRUE` is omitted, it exits instantly.

Is there a way to have `llply` exit as soon as the first error is encountered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I'm afraid it isn't possible. Shutting down a parallel operation early isn't easy since it often requires a lot of complex coordination between the processes that could slow down the operation even in the case when nothing goes wrong, and most people consider that to be undesirable.  Also, it's usually the case that if something goes wrong, it goes wrong in all of the tasks, so early exit doesn't help.  However, it's the sort of feature that when you do need it, you can't imagine why it isn't implemented.

**Update**

I chatted with krlmlr about the possibility of modifying the "doMC" package to use a modified version of the `mclapply` function that would exit as soon as an error occurred. However, the "doMC" package now uses the "parallel" package rather than the "multicore" package (at the request of R-core), and "parallel" doesn't export the low level functions needed to implement `mclapply`, such as `mcfork`, `mckill` and `selectChildren`. If they were used via the `:::` operator, the modified package wouldn't be accepted onto CRAN.

However, I did modify "doMC" to do a quick check for errors when the error handling is set to "stop" so as to avoid the overhead of calling the combine function when errors occur. My tests show that this does improve the performance of the example used in this question, although not nearly as much as if `mclapply` exited as soon as an error occurred. The new version of "doMC" is 1.3.2 and is on R-forge for testing before it is (hopefully) submitted to CRAN.

Comment: Wanna move to [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41129/early-exit-with-parallel-plyr)? I might have a few questions ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, I must have missed when you updated the answer. It's a pity we can't have `mclapply` with early exit, I guess such is life... -- I am now playing with the `BatchExperiments`/`BatchJobs` packages; they also provide a `multicore` backend and allow reading the status and output of each job during execution. Still no automatic termination on error, but much better than being left in the dark. Other backends allow seamless execution on clusters and huge machines. I'd recommend these for any serious parallelization exercise.

Comment: I understand that it would be difficult to actually kill the existing children that have already been spawned, but it seems less difficult to stop spawning new children as soon as you know you won't be using their output.

Comment: @KenWilliams By default, mclapply spawns all of the workers right at the beginning of the computation. But even if the mc.preschedule option was set to `FALSE`, supporting an "early exit" would still require a modified version of mclapply, and that would require forking the parallel package because mclapply is implemented via unexported functions. Unfortunately, one of the big changes from multicore to parallel was to no longer export the low level functions, making it much less useful in my opinion. They did the same thing with snow, with similar consequences.